# Como puedo mockear mongoDb para Unit + Integration Testing en GOLang

Tags: mongodb, go, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy trabajando en la implementación de una REST API en Go con MongoDB, y mi intención es agregar unit testing, pero para hacerlo necesito poder mockear la base de datos. Por el momento la unica forma que encontré de hacerlo es utilizando el paquete de mtest de [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver), pero [mtest - godoc](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/integration/mtest) indica que es inestable.

Alguien sabe de que otra manera puedo mockear la base de datos? O sabe si el paquete que estoy utilizando es confiable?

Comment: Hay infinidad de maneras de conseguir lo que estás preguntando, ahora mismo tu pregunta es demasiado amplia como para poder contestarla, por favor lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Por favor muestranos qué has intentado hasta el momento, agrega el código de tus tests y tambien de la unidad que está siendo testeada